# Skyrim maximum carry capacity

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, What is the absolute maximum carry capacity for the player? Just by leveling up and level perks and without potions, spells, enchantments. Is there a known limit?

Comment: Good thing you added "no potions". Considering the feedback loop between potions of fortify enchanting and enchantments of fortify alchemy, I wouldn't have hesitated with the answer, "**there is no limit, only Zuul**"

Comment: @Yawus there's no direct feedback loop in Skyrim, you can only fortify enchanting/alchemy up to a certain limit and then they don't go further.  The only way to go past that is using the fortify restoration exploit.

Answer (score 9):

Well, let's see.

- Base: 300 pts
- Level-up bonus: 5 pts every time you choose stamina. Max boost = 5*80=400
- Perks: Deep pockets, 100 pts
- Standing stones: Steed, 100 pts

The total is 900 pts. Steed stone, as well as some armor perks, will let you ignore the weight of equipped armor. The heaviest armor is Deadric - a full suit will weigh 15+50+10+6=81 points.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer I can give you is that there is no limit on carry weight, due to the Legendary update smashing the level cap into Oblivion. Because of this update, you can level up, in theory, endlessly, and therefore keep adding onto your maximum carry weight.

Temporary:

- The highest carry weight boost on a potion I've seen is +70, but I'm also a fairly low Alchemy level, so it may be possible to get higher.

Semi-Permanent:

- The Steed Stone gives +100 points of carry weight, as well as letting you ignore the weight of equipped items.
- Deep Pockets, under the Pickpocket skill tree, gives +100 carry weight and requires 50 Pickpocket.
- Various armor pieces give carry weight, and you can also Enchant armor pieces to do the same.

Hope this helps, happy gaming!

Comment: You'll probably hit a limit at the maximum size of the integer that stores carry limit, but 65535 should be enough for anyone. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The default [encumbrance](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Encumbrance_%28Skyrim%29) in Skyrim is 300.

There are permanent solutions to improve carrying capacity:

- Every time you pick Stamina when you level up, your capacity improves by 5.  Since the max level in Skyrim is 80, that is an additional 400 carrying capacity.
- Extra pockets perk in Pickpocket tree adds 100 to carrying capacity.
- The unhindered/condition perks reduces the weight of *worn* light/heavy armor to 0.

Sum these up and your theoretical limit will be 800 + whatever armor you are wearing.

There are also semi-permanent ways:

- The steed stone blessing grants a boost of 100 to carrying capacity.
- Various pieces of armor can be enchanted with fortify carrying weight.

Finally, there are temporary ways:

- Fortify carrying weight potions.

Comment: Note that as of v1.8, Fortify Restoration potions have the added effect of fortifying all enchantments on worn equipment.

Answer (score 0):

The player's inventory space goes up to 300. Ways to increase inventory space is:

- Increase stamina when leveling up [+10].
- Activate the [Steed Stone](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Steed_Stone_(Skyrim)) [+100].
- Apparel with fortify carry weight enchantments [depends on enchantment itself].
- Potions with forify carry weight [Depends on effect itself].

Carry weight is important so you won't be able to move very slowly [luckly for Skyrim, you walk slow while  in previous games, you can't move]. Drop items that you don't need. Each item has an amount of weight in the item in the stats below an item, whether it's 2 or even 0! In the image below, try to look at the weight of the item. the helmet below weighs 5.

[image: weightofitems]

Perks in armor skills allow heavy and light armor to weigh nothing. Well, that's what I can say about carry weight. Good gaming!